# Dealing with pixel divergence after multiplying raster together to give a value of 0 selected pixel

Tags: r, raster

I need your help with an issue I am having with one of my R scripts. Firstly, I have a raster map representing the yield of corn in kg/ha/year for every pixel in an entire region. This map has a resolution of 30m by 30m. I also created a binary raster map representing the zones I want to remove production from or restore, which has the same resolution and extent. My goal was to overlay both rasters and assign a value of 0 to any overlapping pixel. The ultimate objective was to have a map that retains the kg/ha/year yield of corn pixel value while having zero as a value for only the overlapping pixels.

The way I went about doing this:

```
#First I created a function to be able to perform this step numerous time with different zone to restore
agri_model<-function(ras2){ 
  
  ##A)Transforming raster object to the same coordinate system
  ras2_proj <- projectRaster(ras2, JR_agri) #The projectRaster function will take the pilot_r2perc and project the value using the crs of the JR_agri raster layer so they have the same projected coordinate system 

  
   ##B)Multiplying the layer to create the agriculture map with restoration
    ###1)Change the value in the pilot layer
    ras2_proj[ras2_proj == 1] <- 0   #Change all the value that are 1 to 0
    ras2_proj[is.na(ras2_proj)] <- 1 #Change all the NA value to 1
 

    ###2)Multiple the raster layer together
    new_ras2_proj <- ras2_proj * JR_agri # Multiplying the raster layer together so that restore area now have a value of 0 and all the other fields have their original value
return(new_ras2_proj)
}

# After I created a loop to run that function and save the ouput in a list
agri_model_list<-list()  #create an empty list to store the raster layers that will be generated
for(i in perc){  
  agri<-i                #I need to index (give a name) to my percentage in order for the loop to read them properly throughout the loop (in other case it may create error since it could run without following order)
  
  agri_x<-agri_model(ras2=agri_list[[agri]])  #I ask R to run the agri_model function with raster found in the agri_list list and to store the result in the variable name agri_x 
  
  agri_model_list[[agri]]<-agri_x             #Now I ask R to put the result in the empty list agri_model_list I previously created each time it run the function so I will be able to retrieve each of them later
}
```

Everyting work, but when inspecting my ouput in qgis I see some unchange pixel
[image: pixel selected]
[image: all selected pixel didn't change]

I try lot of different thing but nothing seem to help. Anyone has an idea how I could solve this issue?
Thank you for the help !!!